# Stored Procedure returning different results when ran on different servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a query that is ran in a staging and production environment. I want the result, in this particular case, to return nothing. In staging it works as expected. In production, however, I get one row with "NULL" values. Any idea as to what the cause could be?

Working with our DBA he assures me the sproc code is the same and permissions are also the same across the environments.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[vpp_getCloneEntryDetails]
@guid varchar(75)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
Select distinct e.entryID,e.entryGuid, e.chargingDept, e.planCode, e.paymentDate, e.chargeHomeAcct,pl.description as planDescr,
    a.fileName, e.approver1, e.approver2, '' as approver1Txt, '' as approver2Txt
from vppRequests r, vppEntries e
left outer join vppPlans pl on pl.planNum = e.planCode
left outer join vppAttachments a on a.entryGuid = e.entryGuid
where r.requestGuid = @guid
and e.requestGuid = r.requestGuid
ORDER BY e.entryID
```

My result in staging is 0 Rows (empty)
My result in production is 1 Row (all fields = NULL with exception of the last two which both = '')

If I grab the SQL out of the sproc and run it in a query window then Production gives me the empty, 0 Row, result I expected. Does anyone know what could cause this to work differently in my sproc?

Thanks!

Comment: Try running with recompile: EXECUTE [vpp_getCLoneEntryDetails] WITH RECOMPILE;

Comment: Is the data the same on both servers?

Comment: Yes - I copied the data down to staging to replicate.  I'll try the recompile - though I may need to get a DBA to do for me